# favicon the rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, favicon

I followed the advice I found here on stackOverflow, and added the following to the  section of my layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag '/favicon.ico' %>
```

favicon.ico is in my public folder I also tried to place it in the assets/images folder

I restarted the rails server (local development environment on the MAC, Rails 3.2.xxx), but I'm not seeing the favicon. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you refreshed your browsers cache?

Comment: I just did, and I can see it now. Answer it and I'll credit you with the answer. I should have known that (now I remember it was in that one stackoverflow answer, but of course I forgot to do it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three things to check:

- Does the `favicon_link_tag` properly render in the HTML source of your document?
- Does the `favicon.ico` URL that it renders point to a valid file, is the path wrong or do you maybe have a permissions issue with that?
- Did you refresh your browser's cache? In most browsers, do so by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> while reloading the website. See also: [Wikipedia: Bypass your cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBypass_your_cache#Bypass_browser_cache.2C_instructions_for_various_browsers)